# matRipple not working in a specific component

Tags: angular-material

I would like to start an animation on user interaction with `matRipple` attribute directive.

I have tried it with `<i matRipple class="material-icons">create</i>` and imported `MatRippleModule` from `@angular/material`, like this:

```js
import { MatRippleModule } from '@angular/material';
imports: [
  MatRippleModule
]
```

If I click on the element, nothing happens and I don't even get an error message. Why doesn't it work for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figured out that I didn't see any changes because of the background color. I have added `matRippleColor="orange"` and now I see that it works.